# How to clear console errors using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I am using this code to detect console errors logged while executing automated UI tests with ChromeDriver:

```
public static List<LogEntry> getJavaScriptErrors(Level level) {
    return getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).filter(level);
}
```

Prior to executing a step I would like to clear the console log, so I only see errors which were caused by the particular action I am looking to test and not earlier errors during the test setup.

How can I explicitly clear errors from logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this method which clears the console in the browser (first 3 lines) and clears the log returned to Selenium (the last line).

```
public void clearConsoleErrors(){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver();
    String script = "console.clear();";
    js.executeScript(script);
    getDriver().manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER).filter(Level.ALL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to see logs anyway in a .log file you can set property for it.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", "\\path\\chromeDriver.log");
```

After that you can set console logging as silent with below code.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
```